# Optimized way of processing a video in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, video-processing

I have a application that is hosted in GCP.
The application will get a video input and blur the faces in that and gives back the blurred video of the output. (The video is stored in GCS)

Right now, the flow is as follow:

download video to local -> extract frames and save it in gcs -> blur faces in it and store the frame back in gcs -> stich the blurred frames back to a video in local -> upload the video back to gcs

I want to get some ways of optimizing it. Can you give me some suggestion to optimize this process? Let me know if you need more details

Comment: What do you want to optimize?

Comment: I would like to optimize the time taken. One thing I can think of this is something like below:
download video to local -> extract frames to local -> blur and save them in local -> stitch them in local -> upload back to gcs

By doing this I can stop hitting gcs multiple times rather than what I was doing earlier.

Comment: What do you use to blur face?

Comment: a custom trained pytorch model...

Comment: How long are the video? What their size?

Comment: The videos are of different size, some are just 20 seconds and some are like 5 minutes, and I'm expecting to get pretty big videos like 10 minutes, all at approx 30fps

Comment: Less than 10Gb? Just to evaluate the different options...

Comment: Yeah, it should be well below 10Gb

Comment: So, why do you use Cloud Storage? You can process all in memory. like that, you avoid the Cloud Storage latency and greatly increase your process speed!

Comment: Yeah that's what I too thought of when I said: 
 download video to local -> extract frames to local -> blur and save them in local -> stitch them in local -> upload back to gcs. 
Just wanted to know if there were ways to process everything on cloud without downloading the video to local (the input video comes from gcs)

Comment: "Downloading to local" means "nothing". In fact, if you read the video from GCS, the video is stored in the memory of your Cloud Run/Cloud Functions. When you download it, it's stored in a "in memory" storage. Still in memory, but not in a variable in your code. In any case, you have to download the video content into your local memory, whatever the form of it. The other solution would be to update your bluring face model to read data directly from Cloud Storage and perform itself the split in frame (...) but it's too much responsibility for the model.